# How to add data in class within another class

Tags: c#, oop, class

I have one class like below. I want to send one `Messageformat` like this for one webservice, so I need to add values to `Attributecollection` and `Input`.

```
public class Messageformat
{
    public class Attributecollection
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Input
    {
        public string soid { get; set; }

        public string itemname { get; set; }

        public int qty { get; set; }
    }

    public class output
    {
        public string soid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to add values to this class. I can call only one class at a time and add values to that class. Is there any way to call the class `Messageformat` and add values to sub classes through that object. I know its a nested class structure. I am not good in oop so can anyone share some idea about this?

Comment: Not sure but that thing can be achieved by **Reflection**. You need to write down reflection code to fill the subclasses of your class [Filling Data objects using Reflection](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sridhar_subra/filling-data-objects-using-reflection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make each class separate for definition. Then (WCF) you'll be able to create your DataContract and its specify its datamembers - the properties, you what to send in your messages:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class Messageformat
  {    
     [DataMember]
     public Attributecollection prop1;
     [DataMember]
     public Input prop2;
     [DataMember]
     public output prop3;
  } 

  [DataContract]
  public class Attributecollection
  {
     [DataMember]
     public string name { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
     public int id { get; set; }

  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Input
  {
      [DataMember]
      public string soid { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public string itemname { get; set; }
      [DataMember]
      public int qty { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class output
  {
      [DataMember]
      public string soid { get; set; }
  }
```

Then you should generate your Service Contract, where you can use your class

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService
  {
     [OperationContract]
     SendMessage(Messageformat message);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing it like this? Instead of nesting your classes, declare your classes at same level and create properties inside the `MessageFormat` of other classes i.e.

```
  public class Messageformat
  {
     public Attributecollection AtrributeCollection{get;set;}
     public Input Input{get;set;}
     public output Output{get;set;}
  }
  public class Attributecollection
  {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
  }
  public class Input
  {
     public string soid { get; set; }
     public string itemname { get; set; }
     public int qty { get; set; }
  }
  public class output
  {
     public string soid { get; set; }
  }
```

This way, you can easily create an Object of MessageFormat and insert data of all the other three classes i.e

```
  [WebMethod]
  public string GetMessage()
  {
        Messageformat msgFrmt = new Messageformat();
        msgFrmt.AtrributeCollection = new Atrributecollection()
                                         { 
                                             name="test",
                                             id=1
                                         };

        msgFrmt.Input = new Input()
                            {
                               soid= "soid value",
                               itemname="item",
                               qty=10
                            };
        msgFrmt.Output = new output()
                             {
                                soid="soid value"
                             };

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(msgFrmt);
  }
```

above is a simple example, how you can organize your classes and use them for any purpose. (above is an example of a webmethod, but you can do whatever you want)

Comment: What if I did `List<Messageformat> lmf = new List<Messageformat>();` How do I populate it than?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear, but if you're asking how to populate data, you'll have to add what's called *properties* to your parent class. Do note that you don't have to use inner classes.

```
public class Attributecollection
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Input
{
    public string soid { get; set; }
    public string itemname { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
}

public class output
{
    public string soid { get; set; }
}

public class Messageformat
{
    public Attributecollection MyAttributecollection { get; set; }
    public Input MyInput { get; set; }
    public output Myoutput { get; set; }
}

...

Messageformat test = new Messageformat
    {
        MyAttributecollection = new Attributecollection { name = "", id = 1 },
        MyInput = new Input { soid = "", itemname ="", qty = 1 },
        Myoutput = new output { soid = "" }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks/sounds of it, you want an instance of one class that exposes properties of the others:

```
public class Messageformat {

  public MessageFormat() {
    Attributes = new Attributecollection();
    Input = new Input();
    Output = new output();
  }

  public Attributecollection Attributes { get; set; }
  public Input Input { get; set; }
  public output Output { get; set; }
}

public class Attributecollection {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Input {
  public string soid { get; set; }
  public string itemname { get; set; }
  public int qty { get; set; }
}

public class output {
  public string soid { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var format = new MessageFormat();
format.Input.soid = "something";
format.Input.itemname = "something";
```

And so on. There, are lots of improvements to be had here, to be sure, but there you have it.

Comment: What if I did `List<Messageformat> lmf = new List<Messageformat>();` How do I populate it than?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the inner class and its properties **static** in its access level like this:

```
 class MessageFormat
 {
    public static class Attributecollection
    {
        public static string name { get; set; }

        public static int id { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Input
    {
        public static string soid { get; set; }

        public static string itemname { get; set; }

        public static int qty { get; set; }
    }

    public static class output
    {
        public static string soid { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

And then you could access the inner classes although without instantiation:

```
  MessageFormat.Attributecollection.id = 1;
  MessageFormat.Attributecollection.name = "test";
  MessageFormat.Input.itemname = "Soda";
  MessageFormat.Input.qty = 10;
```

Although it defeats the purpose of a nested class because supposedly an inner class of a nested class should be accessible only by the outer or parent class. But as per your requirement this code would meet that requirement.